# Put results of Android Wifi Scan into parsed array

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, parsing

I am trying to build a wireless location footprint system for the University I attend. Using the attached code I am able to view wireless access points and the various information associated with them (BSSID, Signal Strength, encryption protocol etc.) in a list via a string builder.

Ultimately I want wrap the `getScanResults();` data into an array and output the parsed information so that I have only the relevant information that I need to query a database on an external server. (Namely BSSID & Signal Strength)  How can this be achieved?

```
package com.example.wifiscanner4;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class WifiTester extends Activity {
    TextView mainText;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Button scan;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_tester);

     //enable wifi on application start

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getBaseContext()
                     .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
             wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

       mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
       mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
       registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
       mainWifi.startScan();
       mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");
       scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    //protected void onClick(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
     //   mainWifi.startScan();
     //   mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
     //   return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
   // }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
                sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\\n");
            }
            mainText.setText(sb);
        }
    }

 // Upon pressing back button to exit app, wireless function set to disable
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getBaseContext()
                  .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    this.finish();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your receiver code, you are looping a List of ScanResult objects... but you are doing this by incrementing an integer. Maybe try:

```
for (ScanResult result : getScanResults()) { ... }
```

This would give you a way to interrogate "result" and extract the data using the "BSSID" and "level" properties.

See [Android Development Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) for information about ScanResult

Comment: Great thanks Rich. This is exactly what I have done, setting the string format as  'sb.append(String.format(" SSID: %s, BSSID: %s, RSSI: %s dBm ", result.SSID, result.BSSID, result.level));' However, I now need to post this data to a MySQL database for querying. Should I re-post my new code or start a new question thread?